# Finite Fourier Transform of a derivative

Tags: derivatives, fourier-transform

I was trying to take a very basic, differentiable function, and compute the Finite and Inverse Finite Fourier Transforms utilizing the properties of taking a Fourier Transform, but realized that there is an issue when dividing by the frequency term such that it produces a division by 0 where the frequency is 0.

So the rule is that:

$$F\left(\frac{d}{dt}u(t)\right) \longleftrightarrow i\omega\hat{u}, \ \ \ \ F^{-1}\hat{u} = u(t)$$

So, I thought it would follow that:
$$i\omega\hat{u} \xrightarrow[]{divide} \frac{i\omega\hat{u}}{i\omega} = \hat{u} \xrightarrow[]{F^{-1}} F^{-1}\hat{u} = u(t)$$

Where $\hat{u} = u(\omega)$, I just like the hat notation more; $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{L_t}*t$, $L_t$ is the length of $t$ which is the number of points along its axis minus 1. But this did not work due to a division by zero issue as I mentioned already.

In my case I have a differentiable function:

$$p(z) = p_0 e^{-z/H}$$

where I have set $H=40$ and $p_0 = 1000$, the frequency variable is going to be $\zeta$ when we perform the Fourier Transform, and I have set $z = [0,20]$. And I use this to form a basic derivative that we will be working with below:

$$\frac{dp(z)}{dz}$$

My plan of action is the same as I showed in the first 2 equations.

$$F\left(\frac{dp(z)}{dz}\right) = i\zeta\hat{p} \xrightarrow[]{divide} \frac{i\zeta\hat{p}}{i\zeta}$$

And then ideally, I would take then Inverse Fourier Transform of $\hat{p}$ to get back to p, but the problem comes at the division step at $\zeta = 0$ which is also at $z=0$. How do I deal with this issue? I'm assuming take a limit of the Inverse Fourier Transform Integral or apply a boundary condition, but I don't know how to do that for Fourier Transforms. For the boundary condition, I have $p(z=0) = p_0 = 1000$ and I computed the derivative and got $p'(z = 0) = - 25$, but I just can't envision how to apply this to the Fourier integral.

Does anyone have any insight into this problem?

NOTE: I also had to do some other manipulations to treat this as a psuedo-periodic signal by extending the domain and some other steps necessary in order to obtain a proper Fourier Transform representations of the functions as well as their correct Inverse Fourier Transform counterparts, but we won't get into that unless someone asks, because I don't find it pertinent to the heart of the issue.

---

**ADDED INFORMATION**

The formula for the Discrete Time Fourier Transform is:

$$X(e^{j\omega}) = F(x)_{j\omega} = \sum_{n=N_0}^{N_1} xe^{-1j(\omega_n) t}$$

where $N_1$ is the number of points to the right of the line of symmetry of an aperiodic signal and $N_0$ is the number of points to the left. Here is an image below that should illustrate what this looks like (additionally this is what I am trying to use to recover $p(z)$):

[image: z vs dpdz]

Where I used a scatter plot over the line to illustrate each finite point which makes up the Discrete Time function.

So in our case, the computation at $\zeta = 0$ before dividing by $\zeta$ would look like:

$$F\left(\hat{\frac{dp}{dz}}_{N_0}\right) = i\zeta\hat{p}_{N_0} =i\zeta\Bigl( 
\\\frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0}e^{-1j(\zeta_{N_0}=0)*z_{N_0}} = \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0} = -25 +
\\ \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0+1}e^{-1j(\zeta_{N_0} = 0)z_{N_0+1}} = \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0+1} = -24.3827 +
\\ \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0+2}e^{-1j(\zeta_{N_0} = 0)z_{N_0+2}} = \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0+2} = -23.7807 + 
\\ ... + \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_1}e^{-1j(\zeta_{N_0} = 0)z_{N_1}} = \frac{dp}{dz}_{N_1} = -15.1633 
\\ 
\Bigl)$$

and when we divide, that's when the problem arises, and it occurs on the very first term in the summation as we'll see below:

$$F\left(\hat{\frac{dp}{dz}}_{N_0}\right) = \frac{i\zeta\hat{p}_{N_0}}{i\zeta} =\Bigl( 
\\\ \frac{\frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0}}{i(\zeta_{N_0} = 0)} = \lim_{\zeta = \pm \infty \rightarrow 0}{ \frac{\frac{dp}{dz}}{\zeta}} = ? +
\\ \frac{\frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0+1}}{\zeta_{N_0+1} = \frac{1*2*pi}{N_0+1}} +
\\ \frac{\frac{dp}{dz}_{N_0+2}}{\zeta_{N_0+2} = \frac{2*2*pi}{N_0+2}} + 
\\ ... + \frac{\frac{dp}{dz}_{N_1}}{\zeta_{N_1} = \frac{N_1*2*pi}{N_1+2}} 
\\ 
\Bigl)$$

Where you can see the issue arises on the first term in the sum when dividing. I do not know how to approach this problem.

---

**ADDED PLOT**

[image]

Where We can see at $\zeta = 0$, we have a maxima for $F(p(z))$ and minima for $F(\frac{dp}{dz})$ and this value repeats itself at $\zeta = 2\pi$. And again, we are starting from the assumption that we do not know what $p(z)$ is. We have $\frac{dp}{dz}$ and we have it's Discrete Time Fourier Transform which we can see plotted above. So, we only have information as it relates to the derivative and we are seeing if we either can't recover $F(p(z))$ and/or $p(z)$.

As an aside, I also made a note under the title that:

$$(-1)2(N-1)=40 \ \ * F(\frac{dp}{dz}) = F(p(z))$$

. I'd assume this comes from finite differentiation where the values are reduced by division by the scale length of the dimension of differentiation, so multiplying by the scale length can undo the difference equation or something like that. Ultimately I pulled this out of my ass, so **I'd ignore it and treat it as an aside** unless anyone can glean something from this. I tried it for different values of N, and recovered p(z), but I haven't tested it thoroughly for different spacing, functions, etc.

Comment: when you say finite Fourier Transform, are you distinguishing the FT on a periodic domain from the FT on the whole real line? Every derivative has FT that vanishes at omega=0, so there shouldn't be any issue

Comment: I don't really get what you're doing. But my feeling is that you're trying to recover some $u$ from the Fourier Transform of $du/dz$? by the FTC (c.f. "never forget the $+C$") you need to additionally know one more number before you can completely recover $u$, and using the FT isn't going to remove this constraint. So you can recover all the frequencies except the lowest frequency (i.e. the average $\int u dz$)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes I am attempting to recover u using a finite Fourier Transform, that is to say the spacing between points is an integer value and the domain is finite. So for $z=[]0,20]$ I had the spacing set to 1. Also called Discrete Time FT. Continuous, it would be infinite domain with infinitely small spacing.

Comment: @CalvinKhor So basically what I'm trying to do, is prove that the rule for Discrete Time Fourier Transformations on derivatives is correct. That is prove that the Fourier Transform is in fact $i\omega \hat{u}$. If I divided off the $i\zeta$ and take the DTIFT of the remaining $\hat p$ and get back to p, then I could prove that the Fourier Transform does gain the $i\omega$ terms when the DTFT is being taken of a derivative of a function. This was just supposed to be a simple test of the rule. Make sense now?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yeah I think should need some kind of prescribed condition or something of the like, just don't have any experience applying it in this context. I'm going to try writing out the full computation to see if I can't come to a clearer picture of what should be done and try to add it at the end.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I updated the question with info all added at the end to help better illustrate what the problem exactly looks like. Please let me know if I made any mistakes and I will fix them.

Comment: All you should need to do is track the zeroth frequency $\int p dz$ separately.  For all frequencies $k\neq 0$, $\left(\frac1{ik} \mathcal F (p')\right) = \mathcal F p$. Since $\mathcal F(p')$ at $k=0$ is always zero, you can't get any information from it.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Okay then. I was unaware that this was some sort of rule, I must have overlooked in my textbook, but it makes sense I think. If the frequency is zero, then the frequency of occurrence of information there is non-existent or something like that I'm remembering vaguely. One other thing, I don't understand the significance of $\int p dz$ in this context. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: its the zeroth frequency; put $k=0$ in $\int p(z) e^{ikz}dz$. Also I would guess its not expressly said because it follows from not being able to divide by zero; the rule that is always true for all freqs is $\mathcal F(u')(k) = ik \hat u_k$. Before we get to talking about any equalities we need to enforce $k\neq 0$ to even consider the expression $\frac1{ik} \mathcal F(u')$. Then the two together give you the claimed result.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That looks like the Continuous Time Fourier Transform with a positive exponential on e, but that doesn't necessarily matter since k=0, so the sign is negligible. So, I ran $\sum_{n=N_0}^{N_1}p[z]e^{-i(0)z}$ and I got 16,543 + 0i. This value repeats itself due to the periodicity property of Fourier Transforms at $k = 2\pi$ as well and the transform itself looks like a flipped image of the Fourier Transform of $\frac{dp}{dz}$ with absolute maximums at the same frequencies.

Comment: @CalvinKhor So I'm assuming I can turn the division into: $\frac{F(\frac{dp}{dz})}{i*k<0} + 16543 + \frac{\frac{dp}{dz}}{k>0}$ or am I mistaken? Additionally, I'm going to go ahead and add a plot of the Fourier Transforms of $p(z)$ and $\frac{dp}{dz}$ to help give you the bigger picture of what exactly I'm dealing with to add to my previous comment. Thanks for your help thus far!